# django admin template error

Tags: django, django-admin

After uncommenting this line

```
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
```

I am getting template error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably related to your os' locale settings.
Issue the `locale` command in your terminal - you should get something like below as a output:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

If you will get something like this:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE=""
LC_CTYPE=""
LC_MESSAGES=""
LC_MONETARY=""
LC_NUMERIC=""
LC_TIME=""
LC_ALL=""
```

then you need to set it up like that:

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

reload your terminal and try once again.

If this will solve your issue, then just add it to your `.bash_profile` file, so that it will load automatically when logging in.